# React-native datepicker language change using locale isn't work?

Tags: react-native

I am working in react-native datepicker language change, code:

```js
import React from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker'
import 'moment/locale/zh-cn'
import 'moment/locale/fr'

export default class ScheduleDatePicker extends React.Component {
  state = {
    date: ''
  }

  render() {

    return ( <
      DatePicker mode = 'datetime'
      format = 'lll'
      locale = 'fr'

      style = {
        {
          width: 300,
          marginHorizontal: 5
        }
      }
      date = {
        this.state.date
      }
      customStyles = {
        {
          dateInput: {
            flex: 1,
            borderWidth: 0,
            alignItems: 'flex-end'
          },
          btnTextConfirm: {
            color: '#D05B35'
          },
          dateText: {
            fontFamily: 'System',
            fontSize: 15,
            fontWeight: '500',
            color: 'rgba(74, 74, 74, 1)'
          }
        }
      }
      onDateChange = {
        (date) => {
          this.setState({
            date: date
          })
        }
      }
      />
    )
  }
}
```

output:
`24 juil. 2019 16:38`

but can't change inside the datepicker. Days and months name can't be changed what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using wrong local for french https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php
French - Canada = fr-ca
French - Belgium = fr-be

check the link for local code

locale='fr-ca'

Comment: locale='fr-ca' iam already tried can't change inside the datepicker days,months names

Comment: try using this date-picker i personally used it and locale prop is working like charm  'react-native-date-picker';

Comment: if  u r testing in android the locale props is not passed to date picker and in ios its using DatePickerIOS which is of react native as per them, https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/datepickerios#locale
local of ios is listed in this link (for french pass locale='fre') https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html